# Unique identifiers within a 'mailto' link

Tags: email, uniqueidentifier, outlook-2007, mailto

I am sending a bunch of emails to a list of clients, approx 200-500. I am wondering if there is a way I can identify the replies, other than from the email address.

Eg. I could send two emails to the same email address as a husband and wife share that email address.

I am not a code expert by any means (or even an amatuer!) and will be using Outlook to send these emails.

Here is a crude example of what i am using at the moment:

mailto:reidster@work.com?subject=this%20is%20a%20test%201&body=I%20opt%20out%20of%20email%201
&
mailto:reidster@work.com?subject=this%20is%20a%20test%202&body=I%20opt%20out%20of%20email%202

Any assistance much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a rule in Outlook, 
that says Take all Emails from this clients and put them in one folder.
Or if there is the same subject: if there is a subject with this words put them in one folder.

Is it that what you mean ?